# Telehton: Cannot get difference since the account is not logged in?

Tags: python, automation, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to run a script that forwards messages from one specific channel to my Discord server through a webhook. Also I need it to monitor the termination moment to close the session correctly and to log a termination moment in a separate TG channel to let me know if the script was stopped by Ubuntu or something. When I use `client.run_until_disconnected` all works fine, but I can't manage termination moment in that case, so I use this loop instead:

```
terminate_signal_received = False


async def main():
    global terminate_signal_received

    client = TelegramClient(session_name, appid, apihash)
    print(f'Registering events on {input_channels_entities}...')

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=input_channels_entities))
    async def handler(event):
        msg = event.message.message
        await send_to_webhook(msg, event.chat.title)

    # Start the client and run until interrupted or an exception occurs
    try:
        await client.start()
        print("Establishing test message...")
        await client.send_message(log_tg_channel, f"✅ **{name}** is online!")
        print("Client started!")
        # Run until termination signal is received or an exception occurs
        while not terminate_signal_received:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Cancelled!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    finally:
        print("Logging about termination...")
        if client.is_connected():
            await client.send_message(log_tg_channel, f"⛔️ **{name}** was terminated!")
            await client.disconnect()
        else:
            print("Can't! Client is not connected!")


# Signal handler for termination signals
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    global terminate_signal_received
    print(f"Received signal {sig}! Stopping...")
    terminate_signal_received = True


# Register the signal handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

So the script is running and connected all ok, I've got test log message, if I send messages in my "watched" channel they are forwarding to the Discord all good as well, and if I press Ctrl+C telethon send a termination message and log out correctly. But if a script running a few minutes (1-5 randomly) I'm start getting a repeating message from telethon saying:

```
INFO:telethon.client.updates:Cannot get difference since the account is not logged in: AuthKeyUnregisteredError
```

After that, script no longer see for new messages and an interesting part is if I've trying to stop it via Ctrl+C, on the moment it should send a termination log message it crashes with

```
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.AuthKeyUnregisteredError: The key is not registered in the system (caused by SendMessageRequest)
```

no matter that there is `if client.is_connected():` check, so it's thinking that it's connected, but apparently it's not.

Very confusing and I stuck on this for 2 weeks already w/o any progress, so please help...

BTW, today, after a few days of break, the script actually works in my test environment for a half an hour and was successfully terminated after that. But after that it refuse to work both in test environment and on the server.

Comment: The error only occurs when the account is not logged in *but* still has connection. Are you sure the session is active and logged-in? If you check from official clients, does it show there?

Comment: @Lonami I don't want to provide my personal login/pass to the script, so I'm using bot token to log in. Can't find any convenient way to check if bot is logged in or not. Do you have any ideas why it can log out by itself? Maybe I've shouldn't use asyncio.sleep?

Comment: Bots shouldn't be getting logged-out, but you can provide the `bot_token` to `start(...)` which will make it login directly if needed.

Comment: @Lonami thank you for advice, I'm entering token manually every time, so gonna try it right now!

Comment: @Lonami doesn't helped with the issue, it's logging out as well. Also I'm noticed, that internally it's logged out correctly, because at the moment of issue .session file is unlocked and .session-journal file is removed... but I still can't figure out how to prevent this from happening...

Comment: @Lonami btw, if you need the full script, you can get it here https://github.com/ManeFunction/Telegram-To-Discord/tree/mane It's highly modified fork, look at the "mane" branch. I'll be very appreciated if you could help me.